# why add tag name before id selector in JQuery?

Tags: jquery, selector

```
$('a#actionLifeEnforcement').click(function() {
        if(!validateSelectedRightsType()){
            return false;
        };
        if ($("input:checkbox:checked").length == 1) {
            $("input:checkbox:checked").each(function() {
            $('<input>').attr({
                type: 'hidden',
                id: 'id',
                name: 'id',
                value:  $(this).val()
                }).appendTo('form#formLifeEnforcement');
            });
            $('#formLifeEnforcement').submit();
            }else {//....   }
            return false;
    });
```

i dont understand in above code , in the jquery selector , why need add tag name before id? like `a#actionLifeEnforcement` and `form#formLifeEnforcement` ?

Comment: You do not need to add tag name with id selector(as long as they are unique on page)

Comment: it's not required, but it does make the selector run a little faster by narrowing down the element type it's searching for.

Comment: It is used to differentiate the id's between forms , if you have many

Comment: Selectors are read right to left, so you shouldn't as it makes the selector slower.

Comment: @flauntster it runs slower because the element selector will be slower than id selector

Comment: @sankrish id of an element must be unique so I'm not seeing a reason

Comment: You're correct @ArunPJohny, thanks for clearing that up. Selectors with just a ID (eg $('#actionLifeEnforcementare')) are the fastest possible jquery selector type, as it maps directly to the browser's native document.getElementById() function :)

Comment: Conceivably you could have a stylesheet shared between multiple pages, the same `id` appearing on separate pages, but applied to different tags. Not saying it's a brilliant strategy, but it could be an explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is you don't have to use the type of element before the `id` or `class` name in the selector.

The long answer is you should **never** have to use the element name before an `id` selector because `id`s should **always** be unique per page.  The only reason you would ever want to specify the element type before the `id` is if you wanted to note to yourself what type of element you're dealing with.

When it comes to classes, however, you could most certainly be in a situation where you want to have one element of many elements with the same class name that has a certain behavior the others do not.  An example of that would be something like this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $('a.button').click(function( ){ 
     alert("I'm a link that looks like a button!"); 
     return false;
 });
 $('input.button').click(function( ){ 
     alert("I'm an input that looks like a button!"); 
     return false;
 });
</script>

<a href="#" class="button">Link</a>
<input type="submit" name="button" value="Submit Button" />
```

In summary: you're right to question selectors with the element type prepending the `id`.

Hopefully that clears things up.

**Note:** My example implies there is some CSS to make the 2 elements look the same.  That's the reason they share the same class name.

Answer (score 0):

suppose you have the multiple a different tags having same class let say 
 and you want that only "a" tag having class="check" click then only your function get called,to achive this you have to write $("a.check).click(function(){});
it execute faster.

Comment: IDs should be unique within a document regardless of element tag type, so you should never have different tags having the same ID, as your document will be invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Although ids are unique per element in a same page but your question was that

*why add tag name before id selector?*

The simple answer is there is no need to do this with id selectors:

```
$('a#actionLifeEnforcement')
```

The above selector selects only anchor with the specific id but in case of class selectors that would be very significant.

**But in case of class names suppose:**

you have two different tags with same class names:

```
<a class='myclass'>dummy link</a> // an anchor with classname "myclass"
<div class='myclass'>dummy text</div> // a div with classname "myclass"
```

so now in js:

```
$('.myclass')
```

The above selector selects both elems because of same class names but:

```
$('a.myclass')
$('div.myclass')
```

These two  selectors are different from each other and you can perform different operations this way.

#### [Fiddle with same class names with different tags.](http://jsfiddle.net/UM5AT/)